# EF Code First Edit has no effect on mapped entities

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using Entity Framework Code First.
I have two entities:

```
    public class Meal 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MealID { get; set; }


    public virtual List<MealCategory> MealCategories { get; set; }

} 
  public class MealCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MealCategoryID { get; set; }


    public virtual List<Meal> Meals { get; set; }

}
```

They are mapped in the config:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Meal>()
         .HasMany(c => c.MealCategories)
         .WithMany(x => x.Meals)
         .Map(a =>
         {
             a.ToTable("MealCategoryMapping");
             a.MapLeftKey("MealID");
             a.MapRightKey("MealCategoryID");
         });


    }
```

When adding a new meal with an existing Category it works perfectly, the ids are correctly inserted in the mapping table

```
        Meal Meal = new Meal();

        Meal.MealCategories = new List<MealCategory>();

        var categoryToBeAdded = (from x in Context.MealCategoreis where x.MealCategoryID == 1 select x).FirstOrDefault(); 
      Meal.MealCategories.Add(categoryToBeAdded);

        MealDataContext.Add(Meal);
        MealDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, if I try to edit the meal and add new categories nothing happen in the mapping table. The old entries stay the same and the new are not added.

```
    Meal Meal = (from x in MealDataContext where x.MealID == 1 select x).FirstOrDefault();

        Meal.MealCategories = new List<MealCategory>();

        var categoryToBeAdded = (from x in Context.MealCategoreis where x.MealCategoryID == 4 select x).FirstOrDefault(); 
      Meal.MealCategories.Add(categoryToBeAdded);

        MealDataContext.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        MealDataContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        MealDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

No Exception or somethink is thrown. 
Can you please tell me how I can remove all old mapping entries and add new one when editing?

Comment: What is the role of `entityToUpdate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The call to `Collection("MealCategories").Load();` should get EF to create a tracked collection.

```
Meal Meal = (from x in MealDataContext where x.MealID == 1 select x).FirstOrDefault();

MealDataContext.Attach(entityToUpdate);
MealDataContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
MealDataContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).Collection("MealCategories").Load();

var categoryToBeAdded = (
    from x in Context.MealCategories 
    where x.MealCategoryID == 4 
    select x).FirstOrDefault(); 

Meal.MealCategories.Add(categoryToBeAdded);

MealDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

First let  me say that you can use [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to fetch an object from the database (or the DbContext cache if it's already present in the local collection):

```
Meal meal = MealDataContext.Meals.Find(4);
// (lower case variable name is conventional)
```

You should realize that the `meal` object at this point has a `MealCategories` collection that's tracked by Entity Framework. You don't have to, no, *should not* replace it by a new one. If the collection is loaded at that point, replacing it cuts the categories from the owner `meal` and when you save changes the junction records are deleted!

In your case the collection is not loaded, so this does not happen.

It is not entirely clear to me why the category that you add to the `MealCategories` collection is not saved. Maybe because it seems to come from a different context (or is that a typo?). But that should throw an exception. Anyway, make sure that

1. You do not replace the `MealCategories` collection, and
2. Add a category to it that is fetched by the same context instance as the meal

and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add the category using the same context. However, this has no effect on the mapping. I traced the sql, but only the update statement for the meal is generated/ executed. Do you have another idea?

Comment: You fetch the meal, the category, add it to the `meal.MealCategories` collection all in the same context _instance_? (Not multiple instances of the same context _class_).